# Push down all views and add a custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am developing an in-house app; it has been requested that a logo of the app should be on the top of all views, over the navigation bar.

Like this one, Calendar is current the navigation bar in this view;

[image]

I tired

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIView *vMyCustomUIView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,62)];
    vMyCustomUIView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#2896D5"];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:vMyCustomUIView];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, 0, 62);
}
```

Which worked but it just replaced the position of the navigation bar,rest of the items in self.view stayed at the same position of course, also it looks like I have to deal a lot with orientation changes.

So is there a feasible way yo push down each view in the app and put that custom view on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below code->

add `UIWindow *anotherWindow;` as class property (strong reference) or ivar

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    UIWindow *window =[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    window.frame=CGRectOffset(window.frame, 0, 40);//move down the keyWindow.so navigation bar and views will come down
    // add another window on top.
    anotherWindow =[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    anotherWindow.windowLevel =UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    anotherWindow.hidden=NO;

    UIView*view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    view.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
    [anotherWindow addSubview:view];

}
```

**Method 2->**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    UIWindow *window =[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        obj.frame=CGRectOffset(obj.frame, 0, 40);
    }];

    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    view.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view.window addSubview:view];
}
```

But after dismissing this viewController, for method1 don't forget to reset the frame of keyWindow and remove the anotherWindow. For method2, reset the frames of subViews of keyWindow.

**For Method 2**->
Reset the frame of subViews of keyWindow on viewdisappear (viewController removal).

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    UIWindow *window =[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [[window.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    [window.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        obj.frame=CGRectOffset(obj.frame, 0, -40);
    }];
}
```

Comment: `[EventsListViewController setWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`, what should I use instead of self.window?

Comment: Ok nice, almost there,trying to use method 2 now, but how do I reset the frames of subViews of keyWindow, i tried ended up removing everything from current window.

Comment: check the updated answer. if you agree with it, then accept the answer.

Comment: rather than using last object, I used tag property thought it is cleaner that way.